# Booleans with Haml and liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, haml, liquid, locomotivecms

in Haml this works perfectly:
`%input{:disabled => false}`

but Liquid is on top of it, I have tried this `%input{:disabled => {{ isDisabled }} }` no success

Comment: I’m not sure this will be possible, depending on how Liquid and Haml have been combined. Can you give more info on what you are seeing at the moment (i.e. what does “no success” mean)?

Comment: I mean it throw an error.
I manage to make it works by not using haml and use plain html.